Algebraic answer to this percentage question
Given:

$a$ is a whole number, $6\%$ of $a$ is a whole number as well, $a$ is thus divisible by:

Possible answers:
$35, 30, 25, 20$
Now, of course I can try and substitute answers such as $300$ and $100$ etc... but is there a more "number theory" approach to this?
I tried to write the question as so and let's assume $a>0$ for this moment:
$$ a \in \mathbb{N} \\ 0.06a \in \mathbb{N} \\ x| a \\ x = ?$$
Then we can write $0.06a = xr $ but from here I kinda got stuck... Any ideas? without substituting numbers?
Thank you!

Do you know how to convert percentages into fractions?

@lulu I must say, as someone who isn't new on this site, these kind of questions truly hurt, I want to believe that you know that I probably know how to convert percentages into fractions, and yes, I did not write it here, but I've worked out on this question on paper and did this $6/100 = 3/50$ stage. Speaking of probability, it is your main tag, have some respect please!

I apologize for my phrasing.  I ought to have written "Hint:  write the percentage as a fraction."

Let $b$ be 6% of $a$. Six percent corresponds to the fraction $\frac{6}{100}=\frac{3}{50}$. We thus have
$$b = \frac{3}{50}a = \frac{3a}{50} = (3a) / 50$$
The number $b$ has to be a whole number which means that $3a$ must be divisible by $50$. A product of two whole numbers is divisible by another number only if at least one of the numbers is divisible by it. Since $3$ is not divisible by $50$, then $a$ must be divisible by $50$. Otherwise, there would be no way that $3a$ is divisible by $50$ and $b$ won't be a whole number.
But $50 = 5\times 5\times 2$ which means that $a$ is also divisible by $5$, $10$ and $25$.

I'll introduce the variable $r= 0.06a$ for convenience.
Since $a = \frac{100}{6} r = \frac{50}{3} r$ is supposed to be an integer, we see that the integer factorisation of $r$ must contain a factor of 3 (and possibly other factors). Since 3 is the smallest possible value for $r$, we see that 50 is the smallest possible value for $a$, and thus we can know for sure that $a$ is at least divisible by 25, but possibly by the others as well.
